# How to set the right keyboard type in XMADL?

Tags: mobile

I have multiple edit fields defined on the screen. They take first name, last name, email and us-zipcode. How can I change the keyboard such that when the focus is on

- firstname and lastname - the first letter is capitalized
- email - the keyboard shows the symbol “@” and “.com”
- us zipcode - the keyboard shows only digits.

  ```
  <screens>
      <screen name="userprofile" screen_type="SCREEN" allow_reorientation="true" allowed_layouts="BOTH" scroll="VERTICAL"
              width="100" height="100" local_data_source="select lastname, firstname, email, zipcode from user_details where email=&apos;&lt;email&gt;&apos;" >
          <title_controls>
              <control type="TEXT" x="0" y="1" width="100" height="6" default_value="Profile" 
                      appearance_name="white" data_type="VARCHAR">
              </control>
          </title_controls>

          <controls>
              <control name="labelfirstname" type="TEXT" x="2" y="3" width="30" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="First Name"/>
              <control name="editfirstname" type="EDIT" x="35" y="2" width="50" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="edit_box" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="firstname" 
                      default_value="" size="80"/>
              <control name="labellastname" type="TEXT" x="2" y="12" width="30" height="8"
                      appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="Last Name"/>
              <control name="editlastname" type="EDIT" x="35" y="12" width="50" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="edit_box" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="lastname" 
                      default_value="" size="80"/>
              <control name="labelemail" type="TEXT" x="2" y="22" width="30" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="Email"/>
              <control name="editemail" type="TEXT" x="35" y="22" width="50" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="email" 
                      default_value="" size="80"/>
              <control name="labelzip" type="TEXT" x="2" y="32" width="30" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" default_value="Zip Code"/>
              <control name="editzipcode" type="EDIT" x="35" y="32" width="50" height="8" 
                      appearance_name="edit_box" word_wrap="0" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="zipcode" default_value="" size="80"/>
          </controls>
      </screen>
  </screens>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the keyboard type with each edit field using the attribute “keyboard_type”.

- For the controls “editfirstname” and “editlastname” add the attribute keyboard_type=”CAP_WORDS”. This will make the first letter of each work capitalized.

  ```
  <control name="editfirstname" type="EDIT" x="35" y="2" width="50" height="8" appearance_name="edit_box" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="firstname" default_value="" size="80" keyboard_type=”CAP_WORDS”/>
  <control name="editlastname" type="EDIT" x="35" y="12" width="50" height="8" appearance_name="edit_box" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="lastname" default_value="" size="80" keyboard_type=”CAP_WORDS”/ >
  ```
- For the control “editemail” add the attribute keyboard_type=”EMAIL_ADDRESS”. This will make the symbol “@” and “.com” appear on the keyboard

  ```
   <control name="editemail" type="TEXT" x="35" y="22" width="50" height="8" appearance_name="black" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="email" default_value="" size="80" keyboard_type=”EMAIL_ADDRESS”/>
  ```
- For the control “editzipcode” add the attribute keyboard_type=”NUMBER”. The keyboard will only show digits and the characters ‘-’, ‘/’

  ```
  <control name="editzipcode" type="EDIT" x="35" y="32" width="50" height="8" appearance_name="edit_box" word_wrap="0" data_type="VARCHAR" field_name="zipcode" default_value="" size="80" keyboard_type=”NUMBER”/>
  ```

You can read more about keyboard_type [here](http://docs.appemble.com/controls/editcontrol.html#keyboard-types).